# Wifi network problem in ubuntu 16.04lts

Tags: 16.04, wireless, windows

I am using hp laptop with dual boot, ubuntu 16.04lts with window 10. I am not able to connect to my wifi network in ubuntu. Ubuntu is connecting to all other network except my home my wifi network. Channel is wlp19s0. The output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` is

```
Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [103c:81c1]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be
    Kernel modules: rtl8723be
```

Comment: What is the wireless channel and encryption in your home access point? Also please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Comment: `wlp19s0` is not a channel, but the interface name. What is the kernel version `uname -a`?

Comment: Output of uname -a is :-  Linux pratik-burkhawala 4.4.0-31-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 13 00:07:12 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 0):

Update your kernel to 4.8 by running

```
sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-16.04
```

and reboot. This wireless adapter works well on this kernel.

Comment: After installing linux-generic-hwe-16.04 and rebootin it my home wifi is still not visible in wifi drop down menu. Output of uname -a is Linux pratik- burkhawala 4 8.0.41-generic #44~16.04.1-Ubuntu

Comment: Change RF channel in your router to one from 1-11.

Comment: Nothing happen by changing channel to 1-11

Comment: Is format is an option? Pilot6

Comment: Anyone have any solution?